# "Looks OK" or "Looks Good"?

Tags: bug, review-queue

I was recently looking at my [network-wide activity history](http://stackexchange.com/users/4859979/rand-althor?tab=activity) and noticed the following anomaly:

[image: looks good]

When reviewing an item on the Low Quality Posts review queue, the options are "Delete" / "Recommend Deletion", "Edit", "Skip", and "Looks **OK**". Indeed, when I clicked on the relevant review item, I found the "Looks OK" terminology is used on-site:

[image: looks ok]

So which is it: "Looks Good" or "Looks OK"? Is this a bug in the syncing between SFF and the SE network, or what?

<sub>(For the record, I think "Looks OK" is better, since it doesn't necessarily mean *this is a good answer, +1*: it just means *this isn't so terrible that it should be deleted; it's OK*.)</sub>

Comment: Found a similar (old) question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234986/low-quality-review-records-say-looks-good-instead-of-looks-ok As to why, it's because it used to be "looks good" and was changed for the reason you imply. Info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question/232342#232342